How to override Uppy upload file restriction error messages
I am using Uppy upload in Angular, I tried overriding the error messages thrown when a file does not meet the requirement, I have defined Uppy Options.
export const icnUppyOptions = (
  errorMessages: UploadRestrictionsModel,
): UppyOptions => {
  const oneKilobyte = 1_024;
  const maxFileSize = 3 * 10 * oneKilobyte;
  const maxTotalFileSize = 10 * 3 * oneKilobyte;
  const maxNumberOfFiles = 10;
  const allowedFileTypes = ['.stp', '.step'];
  return {
    restrictions: {
      allowedFileTypes,
      maxFileSize,
      maxNumberOfFiles,
      maxTotalFileSize,
    },
    locale: {
      strings: {
        youCanOnlyUploadFileTypes: errorMessages.fileTypeError,
        exceedsSize: errorMessages.fileSizeError,
        youCanOnlyUploadX: {
          0: errorMessages.maxFilesError,
          1: errorMessages.maxFilesError,
        },
      },
    },
  };
};

But the error messages do not get overrided, I still see the default error messages.
This is how I use the options
this.#fileUploadService.uppy
      .use(DragDrop, {
        ...this.dragDropOptions(),
        target: 'icn-feature-file-upload',
      })
      .setOptions(this.uppyOptions());
  }

